# Do the infinitesimal generators of a group need be necessarily exponential

Tags: lie-groups

A vector field is supposed to be an infinitesimal generator of a lie subgroup. Typically to generate a flow on a manifold using a one parameter group of transformations, we do exponentiation of the vector field. Does it have to be necessarily exponential or any other function which can generate the flow will do?

Comment: What other function do you have in mind? It is not like we have a choice here...

Comment: The vector field $X(p)=1$ has the flow $\phi_t(p)=p+t$, nothing exponential about it.